# android device recognized by android studio but not eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i m new in developing android .... i was using android studio first but now i want to use eclipse .. the problem is eclipse does not recognize my android device (while in android studio everything works fine) and i dnt want to use virtual device to run my app... my phone is in debug mode .... its a samsung galaxy grand 19082.... its usb driver is installed in my pc... i have two questions 1.is it enough to keep my phone in debug mode and try to run app from eclipse(which works for android studio) 2.(it may seem silly) is usb driver and OEM driver same thing ?? .............

Comment: You installed `USB Driver`. but have you installed `Android ADB Interface Driver`?

Answer (score 0):

first you must install android USB driver in Android SDK manager then install samsung phone driver from below link then restart adb and eclipse put your device in debug mode and connect usb driver.
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows